# What can I do during a 7 hours flight connection in Lisbon?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, lisbon

Me and my wife will soon take a flight from Geneva to Madeira.
Unfortunately, there will be a 7 hours-long connection in Lisbon.

My question is:
**is it enough time to take a short trip in Lisbon and if it is, what can we visit?**

Some remarks :

- We are both french citizen
- We will carry two cabin lugagges (another one is a checked lugagge)
- The airport looks to be close to the city and there is a direct metro line to the center
- I have never been in Lisbon nor Portugal before

Comment: If you have cabin luggage you probably want to find some storage at the airport for that. See https://www.aeroportolisboa.pt/en/lis/services-shopping/essential-services/baggage-services but it's probably a good idea to call them to check the service is currently available.

Comment: Also, are both flights on the same ticket? If not you would need to pick up your checked luggage, store it as well, and then check it in when you return to the airport (unless the airline allows you to check in that early, which is uncommon).

Comment: @jcaron yes both flights are on the same ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just in Lisbon and can confirm that this is doable. The metro takes 45 minutes to an hour to get to the city center. That would still leave you plenty of time to explore parts of the famous Bairro Alto or Alfama areas. There are also buses and Uber is an option as well. Given that there's not much to do at the Lisbon airport, with that much time I would certainly head to town for a bit. Though do leave yourself plenty of time to get back to the airport. European airports in general are in a bit of a crunch this summer and you'd hate to miss your connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have more than enough time to go to the center, where there is a lot to see. You could possibly also go to the Belém area, where there are some major sights but that would add some time and hassle if going by public transportation.